# How do I add NSButtons from the top instead of from the bottom?

Tags: swift, cocoa

I am currently building a navigation left pane where buttons from the side are added dynamically. I have a NSView subclass that facilitates this

```swift
func addButton(_ service: String) {
    let btn = NSButton()
    btn.bezelStyle = .shadowlessSquare
    btn.frame.size = NSSize(width: 48, height: 48)
    btn.image = NSImage(named: service)
    btn.imageScaling = .scaleAxesIndependently
    btn.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.currentY)
    self.addSubview(btn)
    self.currentY += 58
}
```

It works as desired but buttons are added from the bottom instead of the top:

[Resulting App Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnLHo.png)

How do I make it so that new buttons are added from the top?

For reference, here's my storyboard with the "Servi" view containing the buttons.

[Left Pane Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8S10.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Y goes from bottom to top on macOS (the *bottom* is 0). So don't start with `currentY` at 0 or 10 or whatever you're starting with. Start with `currentY` set to one button height less than the view height, and then *subtract* 58 each time instead of adding.

So, you're getting something like this:

[image]

But if you do what I'm describing, you'll get something like this:

[image]

Comment: Used `self.currentY -= 58` and buttons are now going to the bottom where they get cut off of the window frame.

Comment: Yes but you didn't do the _first_ thing I said, which was to _start_ `currentY` at the top.

Comment: Added screencasts to show that if you do what I said you get the right sort of result.

Answer (score 0):

You could flip your view so that the coordinate system starts at the top left instead.  Just create a new NSView subclass and override `isFlipped`

```swift
class FlippedView: NSView {
    override var flipped:Bool {
        get {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Then add the new buttons to an instance of flippedview instead.